# Return a type based on inner bounding

Tags: java, generics

I have a method for retrieving the relevant "Plugin" that registered a listener service:

```
private static final Map<Class<? extends SubListener>, ListenerPluginPair<?>> listeners = new HashMap<>();

//Retrieves registering plugin
public static <T extends SubListener<?>> Plugin getRegisteringPlugin(Class<T> listener) {
    return ListenerManager.getPair(listener).getPlugin();
}

private static <T extends SubListener<?>> ListenerPluginPair<?> getPair(Class<T> listener) {
    Validate.isTrue(ListenerManager.isRegistered(listener), "Class is not registered with listener manager!");
    return ListenerManager.listeners.get(listener);
}
```

However, I'm wondering if there's a way to return based on the inner bounding of the SubListener, for instance in pseudocode:

```
public static <T extends SubListener<E extends Plugin>> E getRegisteringPlugin(Class<T> plugin) {
    return ListenerManager.getPair(listener).<E>getPlugin();
}
```

I can't actually specify a new generic type bounding inside of the `SubListener<?>`, so is this possible to implement through helper classes or some other magic in Java?

Comment: Could you post an SSCCE with sample listener/plugin pairs?  That would make the question more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out!

Simply make a bound that you'll use later in your inner bound:

```
public static <T extends Plugin> T getRegisteringPlugin(Class<? extends SubListener<T>> listener) {//...
```

Comment: Also `<P extends Plugin, S extends SubListener<P>> P getRegisteringPlugin(Class<S> c)` if you need the type of the class.

Comment: @Radiodef you just blew my mind a bit, seeing as I didn't know about comma-separated type witnesses.